# Network inspector doesn't replace status code - Android Studio Flamingo

Tags: android-studio, retrofit2, app-inspection

I am experimenting with network traffic [inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/network-profiler), a new feature of Android Studio Flamingo. I'm trying to change the status code of a response with a status code of 400 to 200.

During the rule adding process, I tried the following steps in order.

- I entered the information of the endpoint I am trying to request in
  the Protocol, Host URL, Path and Method fields.
- I marked the "Apple rule for status:" 400
- I marked the "Replace with status code:" field as 200
- In the body rules section, I entered the json body that I want to return and marked "Replace entire body".
- Then, I tried to send a request to the same endpoint.

In Network Inspector -> Connection View, the status code of the endpoint request is 200, and the body seems to have changed as I wanted. However, only the body changes in **Retrofit**, the status code remains as 400. Therefore, I cannot test the success case in my code. When I look at the **Okhttp** logs, I see a status code of 400 Bad Request, but the body is what I expected.

There is an issue about Network Inspector [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/279979666) but it has not solved, yet. Is there anyone faced with this problem ?

Regards
Tugce.

Comment: I am seeing the same thing. My code gets the new body, but NOT the new status code.

Comment: Which android studio version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try Android studio Iguana 2023.2.1 Canary 5

There was a bug for replacing status code in Network Inspector feature. It was there from `Flamingo` and fixed in `Iguana | 2023.2.1 Canary 5` & `AGP 8.3.0-alpha05`

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/251452522